# Internal Server error in GoogleDrive V2 API when using maxResults param

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am using GoogleDrive's V2 java client library to list the files from my GDrive.
I am getting the below error from Google end frequently.

```
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
```

We have found that while we set the maxResults to more than 150 we are facing this error frequently for particular users.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Why are you using drive v2?  Can i see [example] even though i would rather not support v2.